# What is the best method for catching Shiny Pokemon in Pokemon Moon?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

I want to catch Shiny Pokemon, but I do not know the best way to find them. How can I catch shiny Pokemon?

Comment: When asking a question, try to fully explain your situation. You could state what you already know and where you're struggling, so that people can understand exactly what information you need. If the answer you have already received is insufficient, then try editing your question to make it clear as to what sort of information you were expecting. Good luck.

Comment: Are you asking about the regular versions of Sun and moon, or the Ultra versions?

Answer (score 7):

The chance of encountering Shiny Pokemon is random, with a base chance of **1 in 4096**, however this chance can be increased in a few ways.

- **[Shiny Charm](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Shiny_Charm)** - A Key Item awarded upon completing the Alolan Pokedex, which increases the chance to encounter a shiny to **3/4096**.
- **[Chaining](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Chaining)** - You can use an Adrenaline Orb in SOS battles (where the enemy Pokemon calls another Pokemon to the battlefield) to 'chain encounter' the same Pokemon over and over again. [According to Bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/SOS_Battle#Other_wild_Pok.C3.A9mon), a chain of 31 will increase the shiny chance to **13/4096**

Of course, some Pokemon can't be found in SOS Battles, so you'll need to either encounter them without chaining, or breed for them. The Shiny charm still helps with breeding, as well as using the [Masuda method](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Masuda_method).

Answer (score 1):

If you're playing the Ultra versions you can also get (some, not all) shiny Pokemon through getting decently far in the wormhole minigame. The odds on this are broken down over [here at Serebii](https://www.serebii.net/ultrasunultramoon/ultrawormholes.shtml).

Speaking from my own experience, I've had more luck with this than with shiny hunting via random encounters, SOS chaining or even breeding.

Comment: The question is about Pokémon Moon, which doesn't have wormholes.